How to Bridge Transfer File with TCP From Desktop to Android
Hey I am making simple App that send message with UDP, and send file with TCP from PC to android with QT
but the transfer always in 99% so file never received
Transfer 99%
and i trying with qt quick too with the same logic, its end up like this (fyi the file is not saved)
enter image description here
here is my code for server
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDataStream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    localFile(nullptr)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    initTcpServer();
    initUdpServer();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    tcpServer->close();
    if (localFile && localFile->isOpen())
        localFile->close();
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::initTcpServer()
{
    tcpServer = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(tcpServer, &QTcpServer::newConnection, this, &MainWindow::acceptTcpConnection);
    if (!tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 7600)) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "QTCP Server", "Unable to start the server.");
    }
}

void MainWindow::acceptTcpConnection()
{
    tcpSocket = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(tcpSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::readTcpData);
    connect(tcpSocket, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, [this]()
    {
        ui->statusCurrent->setText("Disconnected");
    });

    ui->statusCurrent->setText("Connected");
}

void MainWindow::readTcpData()
{
    QByteArray data = tcpSocket->readAll();
    // Here, add your logic to handle received data
}

void MainWindow::initUdpServer()
{
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::Any,7501, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
    connect(udpSocket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::readUdpData);
}

void MainWindow::readUdpData()
{
    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(int(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize()));
        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
        ui->textBrowser->append(tr("Received UDP message: %1").arg(QString::fromUtf8(datagram)));

    }
}

void MainWindow::startTransferFile()
{
    if (!localFile) {
        localFile = new QFile(fileName);
        if (!localFile->open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
            QMessageBox::critical(this, "QTCP Server", "Unable to open the file.");
            return;
        }
        totalBytes = localFile->size();
    }

    QByteArray buffer;
    QDataStream out(&buffer, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_15);

    QString currentFileName = fileName.section('/', -1);
    out << qint64(0) << qint64(0) << currentFileName;

    totalBytes += buffer.size();
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << totalBytes << qint64((buffer.size() - sizeof(qint64) * 2));
    bytesToWrite = totalBytes - tcpSocket->write(buffer);

    while (!localFile->atEnd()) {
        buffer = localFile->read(qMin(bytesToWrite, qint64(4 * 1024)));
        bytesToWrite -= tcpSocket->write(buffer);
    }

    localFile->close();
    delete localFile;
    localFile = nullptr;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    startTransferFile();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this);
    if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
        ui->statusbar->showMessage("File selected: " + fileName.section('/', -1));
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    QString message = ui->lineEdit->text();
    QByteArray datagram = message.toUtf8();
    QHostAddress a;
    QHostAddress b;
    QHostAddress c;
    a.setAddress("192.168.1.10");
    b.setAddress("192.168.11.10");
    c.setAddress("192.168.8.118");
    udpSocket->writeDatagram(datagram, c, 7500);
    ui->textBrowser->append("Sent: " + message);
}


for UDP i just Brute it with pair to pair the IP, I try to broadcast it but android never received so i do that
this is code for client
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDir>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    tcpClient(new QTcpSocket(this)),
    udpReader(new QUdpSocket(this)),
    totalBytes(0),
    bytesReceived(0),
    fileTransferInProgress(false),
    localFile(nullptr)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    udpReader->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 7500, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
    connect(udpReader, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::readUDPMessage);
    connect(udpReader, qOverload<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>(&QUdpSocket::errorOccurred), this, &MainWindow::displayErrorUDP);
    connect(tcpClient, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::readTCPData);
    connect(tcpClient, &QTcpSocket::errorOccurred, this, &MainWindow::displayError);

    connectToServer();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    if (localFile) {
        localFile->close();
        delete localFile;
    }
}

void MainWindow::connectToServer()
{
    //tcpClient->connectToHost("10.147.17.205", 8081);
    //tcpClient->connectToHost("192.168.11.104", 7600);//WIFI REKA
    tcpClient->connectToHost("192.168.1.10", 7600);//Ucup
}

void MainWindow::readUDPMessage()
{
    while (udpReader->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(int(udpReader->pendingDatagramSize()));
        udpReader->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
        ui->textBrowser->append(tr("Received UDP message: %1").arg(QString::fromUtf8(datagram)));

        QPixmap pic("file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG" + QString::fromUtf8(datagram));// HP
        //QPixmap pic("storage/emulated/0/Download/" + QString::fromUtf8(datagram));// AVD

        // Menyesuaikan skala gambar
        QPixmap scaledPic = pic.scaled(ui->image->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

        ui->image->setPixmap(scaledPic);
    }
}


void MainWindow::readTCPData()
{
    if (!buffer.size())  // Pastikan buffer sudah diinisialisasi dengan ukuran yang tepat
        buffer.resize(bufferSize);

    QDataStream sendIn(tcpClient);
    sendIn.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_0);

    // Penerimaan header hanya dilakukan sekali
    if (bytesReceived < sizeof(qint64) * 2) {
        if (tcpClient->bytesAvailable() >= sizeof(qint64) * 2) {
            sendIn >> totalBytes >> fileNameSize;
            bytesReceived += sizeof(qint64) * 2;
        }
    }

    // Penerimaan nama file hanya dilakukan sekali
    if (fileNameSize > 0 && fileName.isEmpty() && tcpClient->bytesAvailable() >= fileNameSize) {
        sendIn >> fileName;

        // Construct the new file path
        QString filePath = "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG" + fileName; //HP
        //QString filePath = "storage/emulated/0/Download/" + fileName; //AVD
        localFile = new QFile(filePath);
        if (!localFile->open(QFile::WriteOnly)) {
            qDebug() << "Cannot open file for writing";
            return;
        }
        ui->label->setText(tr(u8"Received %1 ...").arg(fileName));
        bytesReceived += fileNameSize;
        fileNameSize = 0;  
    }

    // Membaca data yang tersisa dan menulis ke file
    while (tcpClient->bytesAvailable() > 0 && bytesReceived < totalBytes) {
        qint64 bytesToRead = qMin(tcpClient->bytesAvailable(), (qint64)buffer.size());
        qint64 bytesRead = tcpClient->read(buffer.data(), bytesToRead);
        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            localFile->write(buffer.data(), bytesRead);
            bytesReceived += bytesRead;
        }
    }

    // Update progress bar
    ui->progressBar->setMaximum(totalBytes);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(bytesReceived);

    // Selesaikan transfer file
    if (bytesReceived == totalBytes) {
        localFile->close();
        ui->label->setText(tr(u8"Successfully received file %1").arg(fileName));
        delete localFile;  // Penting untuk menghapus pointer
        localFile = nullptr;
        totalBytes = 0;
        bytesReceived = 0;
        fileName.clear();
    }
}


void MainWindow::displayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "Network error", tcpClient->errorString());
    tcpClient->disconnect();
}

void MainWindow::displayErrorUDP (QAbstractSocket::SocketError)
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "UDP Network Error", udpReader->errorString());
    qDebug() << "UDP Error occurred:" << udpReader->errorString();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString message = ui->lineEdit->text();
    QByteArray datagram = message.toUtf8();
    udpReader->writeDatagram(datagram, QHostAddress::Broadcast, 7501);
    ui->textBrowser->append("Sent: " + message);
}


Is there something different and need to make a note of how android take a file or TCP data ?
i already make a permission like this
permission
How to make file transfer 100% and got received in the phone

Note that tcpSocket->write might return -1 which will probably cause a bug in your program https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#write

Can you reproduce this issues with two programs running on your desktop? That will improve your cycle times and eliminate Android as a potential problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
